# Error when executing Job with Quartz in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I am using quartz in spring boot project where I want to repeat every 1 minute my service methode repeat()
But I have this Error :

```
Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
NOT STARTED.
Currently in standby mode.
Number of jobs executed: 0
Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not 
clustered.

org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception.
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213) ~[quartz-2.3.2.jar:na]
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573) [quartz- 
2.3.2.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.ssm.Quartz.QuartzJob.execute(QuartzJob.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202) ~[quartz-2.3.2.jar:na]
... 1 common frames omitted
```

*This is my main method*

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws SchedulerException  {
    SpringApplication.run(InventoryApplication.class, args);
    JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(QuartzJob.class).build();
    Trigger t2 =  TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("CronTrigger")
            .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *")).build();
     Scheduler sc = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
    sc.start();
    sc.scheduleJob(job, t2);}
```

*QuartzJob class*

```
public class QuartzJob implements Job {


@Autowired private ProduitService produitService;
@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
    System.out.println("Updated");
    produitService.Repeat();
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because Quartz creates the instance of job via constructor. Then injection of `ProduitService` does not happen and `produitService` is `null`. And when `produitService.Repeat();` is invoked, then `NullPointerException` is thrown.

Comment: So what is the solution ?